# Does Facebook Messenger send a ConversationUpdate message when a user deletes their conversation?

Tags: botframework, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

In the Bot Framework, a the `MessageType.ConversationUpdate` is described as follows:

> This notification is sent when the conversation's properties change, for example the topic name, or when user joins or leaves the group.

When a bot is connected to the Facebook channel, do they receive a `ConversationUpdate` message (or any other system message) when a user deletes their copy of the conversation in Messenger, or does the deletion only occur on the user's end without any notification to the bot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No notification is sent when a person deletes a conversation. But even if they delete the conversation, you can still send messages to them inside the 24hour standard messaging window.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I actually wanted to ensure the opposite -- I wanted to try to suppress further follow-up messages if a user has deleted their conversation.

Comment: No problem! I'd suggest against taking conversation deletion as an indication that the person doesn't want to receive further messages. Many people treat Messenger in an inbox zero style.

Comment: For sure - there's just a specific case where the follow-up message we're sending isn't as useful when removed from the context of the previous messages. It's not a breaking issue, though. Thanks for the information!